# Show Hide using style not working

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please explain to me why this plain-jane web page does NOT do what it is supposed to do, that is to say, change the style from `display:none;` to `display:block;` ??

thanks!

```js
function ShowHideModal(elemID) {
    var Selem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    if (Selem != null)
    {
        if (Selem.style.display == "none")
            Selem.style.display = "block;"
        else
            Selem.style.display = "none;"
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: ShowHideModal('test1');">TryIt</a>
<div id="test1" style="display:none;">
    This is my content baby!
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing the semicolon from "block;" and "none;"

Comment: if you set the value of display to 'none;' (display == "none;") , it wont be equal to 'none'

Comment: @Rhumborl omg i'm dumb... those were supposed to end the line/command... not be in the quotes. My bad! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are placing the "`;`" inside the quotations for "`block;`" and "`none;`".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>

  <a href="JavaScript: ShowHideModal('test1');">TryIt</a>
  <div id="test1" style="display:none;">
    This is my content baby!
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideModal(elemID) {
      var Selem = document.getElementById(elemID);

      if (Selem != null) {
        if (Selem.style.display === "none") {
          Selem.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          Selem.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```